how copy specific cells from one worksheet to another, on varying rows with spaces. Somehow use index match?
I have a worksheet with three tabs. Client facing 'Form", "List" to paste in CRM extracted information, and "Data" to house any needed interim data.
The pertinent information extracted from the CRM is two columns, Column A the 'Regions' and Column C the 'Item Names'.
I want to use VBA code to take the information from "List" and display it on "Form" with the Region Name then in the same column list the items for that region. Leave a space and continue.
Example:
Airport
Toy Robot
Uno Card Game

Commercial
Dinosaur Figures
Glass Marbles
Kids Makeup Kit
Lego Bricks
Nerf Gun
PlayDoh Can
PlayDoh Toolkit

Residential
Deck Of Cards
Dino Egg
Dinosaur Figures
Glass Marbles
Kids Makeup Kit
Lego Bricks
Mini Ping Pong
Monopoly

Downtown
Lego Bricks
Nerf Gun
PlayDoh Can


I've used VBA code for figure out how many items are listed for each region and store that in tab "Data". Column A for the region and Column B for the number of items listed for that region.
For sample:
Airport         2
Commercial  7
Residential 8
Downtown    3
Next I have code that setups the Region Names, leaving space for the Items.
Airport
Commercial
Residential
Downtown

Now I'm trying to figure out how to add the accompanying Item Names under each Region on tab "Form".
I've tried using Index Match with a loop, but it's not looping the right amount of times, nor taking the empty rows into consideration.

This code works in my sample file if i run it in sheet "Form". The data entry in sheet "Form" starts in cell A10 and there is no data in sheet "Form" when the macro is started. Like in your example the data is sorted in sheet "List". The code works as well if there is only one entry for a region.
Sub regions()

Dim i, j, l, m As Long

Range("A:A").Clear

j = 10

For i = 2 To Worksheets("List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
 (Worksheets("List").Range("A:A"), Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 1))


  If l = 1 Then
       Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(j + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 3).Value
    j = j + l + 2
 Else



  If Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 1).Value = _
  Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value And _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), _
Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 1)) = 0 Then




    Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("List").Cells(i, 1).Value
    
    For m = 1 To l
    Cells(j + m, 1).Value = Worksheets("List").Cells(i + m - 1, 3).Value
    Next m
    
    j = j + l + 2
 

Else

End If

End If

Next i

End Sub


(Disclaimer: depending on your version of Excel, not all of these functions may be available.)

Let's break this down into steps: first, you want a unique list of the Regions.  Then, for each Region, you want to get the list of Items.  Finally, you want to Stack all of those up.
So, for the first step, we can use UNIQUE and FILTER:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$A:$A, --(List!$A:$A<>"Region")*--(List!$A:$A<>"")))

(Note that the FILTER is to remove the Heading and Empty Cells.  You can change "Region" to List!$A$1 if you want things to be more ‘dynamic’)
Now, we're going to want to act on each record in that Array/list, so let's use REDUCE and LAMBDA:
=REDUCE("", UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$A:$A, --(List!$A:$A<>"Region")*--(List!$A:$A<>""))), LAMBDA(arr, val, [SOME FUNCTION]))

This will take the arr value (which starts as ""), and apply <SOME FUNCTION> to it for every value (val) in the Array.  So, reviewing our steps: “first, you want a unique list of the Regions.  Then, for each Region, you want to get the list of Items.  Finally, you want to Stack all of those up.”  So far, we've done everything in Bold: let's “get the list of Items” for val as our next step:
UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$C:$C, List!$A:$A=val))

Finally, we want to stack everything up, vertically, with a blank row between them.  For that, we can use VSTACK:
VSTACK(arr, val, [LIST OF ITEMS], "")

Breaking that down: we want to take our arr thus-far, add val (the Region) as a header, then our List of Items we worked out a moment ago, and finish up with an empty cell ("").  So, put it all together:
=REDUCE("",UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$A:$A, --(List!$A:$A<>"Region")*--(List!$A:$A<>""))), LAMBDA(arr, val, VSTACK(arr, val, UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$C:$C, List!$A:$A=val)), "")))


Now, if you run that, you may notice that it includes a blank row at the top (because arr starts out as ""), and a blank row at the bottom (because we add a blank row after every list of items).  If you want to get rid of these, you can use the DROP function: a Positive number with remove that many Rows/Columns from the Top/Left of the array, while a Negative number will remove them from the Bottom/Right.  We want to remove one of each, so we'll need to DROP twice:
=DROP(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$A:$A, --(List!$A:$A<>"Region")*--(List!$A:$A<>""))), LAMBDA(arr,val, VSTACK(arr, val, UNIQUE(FILTER(List!$C:$C, List!$A:$A=val)), ""))), 1), -1)

